# How can I extract data using API in Python using "request" import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.exchangerateapi.io/latest'
response = requests.get(url)
print (response)
```

This is my code. However I am getting this message:

```
 File "C:/Users/tmali/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/web.scraping.py", line 3, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\tmali\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tmali\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tmali\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tmali\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tmali\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.exchangerateapi.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /latest (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002782B377F40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Requests ConnectionErrorr \[11001\] getaddrinfo failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59206196/python-requests-connectionerrorr-11001-getaddrinfo-failed)

Comment: Have you tried to access the URL in question in your browser? I can't seem to even get a valid DNS response for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorize each request to exchangerateapi.io with an API Key which you can get for free by signing up to their service [HERE](https://exchangeratesapi.io/documentation/). Additionally, the free account doesn't support HTTP encryption so http:// will need to be used instead of https://.

Once you have an API Key you can add it to the **access_key** parameter for the query url:

```
url = 'http://api.exchangeratesapi.io/v1/latest?access_key=API_KEY"
```

To check if the call is successful try using print(response.status_code). If successful there should be a 200 returned.

Please refer to their API docs for any additional information [HERE](https://exchangeratesapi.io/documentation/).

Comment: I am getting response 401 :(

Comment: @3okhir Try using http:// instead of https://. It looks like their free plan does not support HTTPS encryption. I spun up a free account and tried with http:// and got a successful response. I have updated my initial answer with this information. Please select my response as the answer if it works for you. :)